# Java XMLGregorianCalendar format

Tags: java, xml, date, xmlgregoriancalendar

I am currently stuck with XMLGregorianCalendar formatting problem and would like to seek help from you java gurus. With a function call from other system, I got a data object displayed on web page with "SUBMIT_DATE":1516032000000 and "SUBMIT_TIME":36895000 (both with returned type XMLGregorianCalendar). How can I know the correct human readable date and time in this case?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: In Java, are you getting two `XMLGregorianCalendar` objects? Or the two numeric values displayed on the web page?

Comment: Well, I am getting a complex type that contains multiple attributes via a RFC. The returned objects contained two attributes with type XMLGregorianCalendar.

Comment: Thanks for providing this information. What is the result of the `toString` method in each of those two attributes? Asking because `XMLGregorianCalendar` is very flexible with which fields are defined and which not, so we need to know which of the two objects have a time zone field defined, and if they both have, whether the time zones agree. Also, when providing more information it’s best to edit the question so we have all information in one place.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and your reminder. Unfortunately, I did not see any other field which shows any information in regard to time zone. I had this question up was because the SUBMIT_DATE/ SUBMITE_TIME field were nowhere parsed to any other type (Date/ GregorianCalendar...) in the code but seemed to be displayed as 1/16/2018, 6:14:55 PM. I would keep looking and try the method you provided below. Thanks!

Comment: Let us know how it goes. If results are not as desired, I am sure we can fix the problem so they are.

Answer (score 2):

### Update after clarification

```
    // We first need to check that the fields we need are defined
    if (submitDate.getTimezone() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No time zone defined in submit date " + submitDate);
    }
    if (submitDate.getYear() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
            || submitDate.getMonth() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
            || submitDate.getDay() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Date not defined in submit date " + submitDate);
    }
    if (submitTime.getHour() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
            || submitTime.getMinute() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
            || submitTime.getSecond() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Time of day not defined in submit time " + submitTime);
    }
    if (submitTime.getTimezone() != DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
            && submitTime.getTimezone() != submitDate.getTimezone()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Conflicting offsets " + submitDate.getTimezone() 
                + " and " + submitTime.getTimezone() + " minutes");
    }

    // then format into a human readable string
    final ZoneId userZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Taipei");
    final Locale userLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-TW");
    DateTimeFormatter localizedFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG)
            .withLocale(userLocale);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = submitDate.toGregorianCalendar()
            .toZonedDateTime()
            .with(LocalTime.of(submitTime.getHour(), submitTime.getMinute(), submitTime.getSecond()))
            .withZoneSameInstant(userZone);
    String humanReadableDateTime = dateTime.format(localizedFormatter);
    System.out.println(humanReadableDateTime);
```

This prints:

> 2018年1月16日 上午10時14分55秒

I am assuming that `submitDate` and `submitTime` are `XMLGregorianCalendar` objects that you have got from the complex object that you have received from a remote system. I am further assuming that you can require the date to contain a UTC offset. Though the method is called `getTimezone`, what it really returns is not a time zone, but an offset in minutes from UTC (or GMT). The extensive checks in the four `if` statements are necessary because `XMLGregorianCalendar` is very flexible with which fields are defined and which not.

To display the date and time in a format suitable for a user audience, you need to know that audience’s *time zone* and *locale*. Once you know those, please fill them in in the above snippet. If you trust the JVM’s settings, you may use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` and/or `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` You may also choose between format styles `FULL`, `LONG`, `MEDIUM` and `SHORT`.

If you don’t receive an offset, you will need to rely on the date and time already being at the user’s offset. On one hand it’s simpler, on the other hand it is more fragile since if the date and time are given at another offset than the user expects, s/he will receive incorrect information, which is worse than receiving no information at all. First check that there is indeed no offset:

```
    if (submitDate.getTimezone() != DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
            || submitTime.getTimezone() != DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected offset");
    }
```

Also check that required fields are defined, this is the same as before. Then create a `LocalDateTime` object and format it:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(
            submitDate.getYear(), submitDate.getMonth(), submitDate.getDay(), 
            submitTime.getHour(), submitTime.getMinute(), submitTime.getSecond());
    String humanReadableDateTime = dateTime.format(localizedFormatter);
```

I got the same result as above.

### Original answer

```
    final ZoneId userZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Taipei");
    final Locale userLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-TW");
    ZonedDateTime submitDateTime 
            = Instant.ofEpochMilli(submitDate + submitTime).atZone(userZone);
    DateTimeFormatter localizedFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG)
            .withLocale(userLocale);
    String humanReadableDateTime = submitDateTime.format(localizedFormatter);
    System.out.println(humanReadableDateTime);
```

This prints

> 2018年1月16日 上午10時14分55秒

To display the date and time in a format suitable for a user audience, you need to know that audience’s *time zone* and *locale*. Once you know those, please fill them in in the first two lines of the above snippet. If you trust the computer’s settings, you may use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` and/or `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` You may also choose between format styles `FULL`, `LONG`, `MEDIUM` and `SHORT`. For this purpose I think you can ignore the information that the returned type is `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

As @user unknown in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49605031/5772882) I am assuming that you can just add the two numeric values. The first almost certainly denotes milliseconds since the epoch, the sum probably too. So why were they passed as two values and not just one? My best guess is that they pass the date separately for any client that just needs the date and not the time of day. The date value falls at midnight in time zones at offset +08:00, this would agree with China, Philippines, Malaysia and a dozen other time zones.

If instead of the numbers you have got two `XMLGregorianCalendar` objects, getting the date and time is a different story, but you may still use the same way of formatting them.

Answer (score 1):

```
    final GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(date);
    return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(
        calendar);
```

This should work..
Pass your millisecs

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs look like they're just the date without time in milliseconds and the time without date in milliseconds.

If you divide both values by 1000:

```
date -d @1516032000
Mo 15. Jan 17:00:00 CET 2018
date -d @36895
Do 1. Jan 11:14:55 CET 1970
```

Well - but why 17:00:00? Maybe a time zone issue.

Here is the aggregate:

```
date -d @$((1516032000+36895))
Di 16. Jan 03:14:55 CET 2018
```

The various date/time formats for Java have methods, which take a long parameter for seconds since epoch (1.1.1970) to set the time.